# jquery datatable and cakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, datatable

i am trying to implement [jquery datatable](http://www.datatables.net/index), in my cakePHP based website, but it just wont load. this website is already half developed, and from the way i see it, the js' is loaded through a file called `_head.inc.ctp` located inside the `views/layouts` folder, i have added the datatables library inside the libs folder which is `webroot/js/libs` and load it inside the `_head.inc.ctp` file.

suppose i have this:
my controller:

```
var $helpers = array(
    'Form',
    'Html',
    'Javascript'
);
//my method
function dataTable_example($id=null){
    $details = $this->Detail->find("all");
    $this->set('details', $details );
}
```

my view:

```
<div>
    <?php echo $javascript->link('libs/jquery.dataTables.js'); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#js-datatable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
    <h2><?php echo __l('Tickets');?></h2>
    <div>
        <table id="js-datatable">
            <tr>
                <th>some heading 1</th>
                <th>some heading 1</th>
                <th>some heading 1</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if (!empty($details)){
                foreach ($details as $detail):
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $detail['Detail']['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $detail['Detail']['created'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $detail['Detail']['ticket_detail'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                endforeach;
            }else{
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

i even hard coded it using the usual call, and checked it using firebug to see if the script is loaded or not, and according to firebug, it is loaded, so i cant see whats making the script fail my table.

did i missed some steps ? please help

thanks

Comment: Have you included the Javascript and HTML helpers in your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have thead and tbody elements as [required by the datatables script](http://www.datatables.net/usage/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the find function in your controller and pass the array to the view and in the view write it.. don't just leave the table empty

Comment: i know, i did that actually, i didnt wrote that on my question just to make things simple, i'll edit the question then, thanks

Comment: Maybe give us a link so we can look at it.

Comment: too bad that i am still developing this in my local